# Sidebar pagination posts not shown when sidebar is in single.php

Tags: pagination, navigation, sidebar, paginate-links

A quick question. So I have created a loop in a new file called `sidebar-extra.php` which **I include via the `header.php` into my `single.php` file**.

**Problem:** when I go to a post (single.php), I can't see this navigation, while I can see it on my homepage, where I also include `sidebar-extra.php`

```
<ul class="pagination">
        <li class="page-item"><?php previous_posts_link('&laquo; Previous posts') ?></li>
        <li class="page-item"><?php next_posts_link('Next posts &raquo;') ?></li>
    </ul>
```

Is there a way I can make sure that `my sidebar-extra.php` is showing the post navigation everywhere, including on `single.php`?

Answer (score 0):

You’re using `previous_posts_link` (and `next_posts_link`) function in your code.

This function prints a link to the previous set of posts within the current query. So they are meant for posts archives.

But if you’re on single page/post, so there is only one post in the query - the one that is shown. So these links won’t be available.

When seeing a single post, you should be using [`previous_post_link`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/previous_post_link) instead (singular post and not posts).

Comment: I don't think that this will solve my issue. I mean, the sidebar has a list of posts and is being injected into single.php but also other pages. How can I make sure it will serve the navigation for all pages, regardless of whether it's single.php or something else? I mean, if I do what you tell me to do, I don't get the navigation in my sidebar area when I am entering single.php, still.